# Aurelia - no ModifyCollectionObserver for a nested array referenced by a computedFrom decorator?

Tags: aurelia

So let's assume my class is something like this:

```
import { computedFrom } from 'aurelia-framework';

export class Test {

    myObj;

    @computedFrom('myObj.myArray')
    get someProperty() {
        debugger;
        return JSON.stringify(this.myObj ? this.myObj.myArray : this.myObj);
    }

    attached() {
        this.myObj = {
            myArray: []
        };

        setTimeout(() => this.myObj.myArray.push('foo'), 500);
    }

}
```

and my HTML is just:

```
<template>
    <h3>myArray value: ${someProperty}</h3>
</template>
```

I've got an issue where `someProperty` is not being updated when I push an element into `myObj.myArray`. I verified this with the debugger in the `someProperty` getter. When `this.myObj` is originally set in `attached` and the `someProperty` getter is subsequently called, I see that `myObj` is a `SetterObserver` in `this.__observers__`.

However, I don't see any `ModifyCollectionObserver` for `myArray` in `this.myObj.__observers__` (in fact, that `__observers__` property doesn't even exist). I would expect that there would be some sort of observer on the array since it is specified as a dependency in my `computedFrom` decorator.

Comment: Does `@computedFrom('myObj.myArray.length')` work?

Comment: @AshleyGrant That does work, thanks! If you leave that as an answer, I'll accept it. However, I was hoping there would be a less-hacky way of doing this.

Comment: Yeah, without using Proxies, there isn't a less hacky way that I'm aware of, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your `computedFrom` decorator to the following and things will start working:

```
 @computedFrom('myObj.myArray.length')
```

This is because the `length` property will change when you push an item in to the array, and Aurelia can observe that change.